# Export STFDF to csv

Tags: r, geospatial, gstat

I have a `STFDF` object (spatio-temporal) with three properties `@data`, `@sp` and `@time` and I want to export the data to a csv file of the following format:

```
latitude    longtitude    timestamp    Value
```

How to do it in R?

Comment: Check the str() of the file. It could help you.

Comment: Have you tried `as.data.frame(x)` ?